# Access Primary Key usage/role

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, ms-access, primary-key

My question is in relation to connecting a VB.net project to an Access DB. 
Must I have a primary key in my table, or have is there a way to alter my code to not look for a PK?

I have an error popping up telling me that I have no primary key. Now if i make "AdminID" my primary key, the system works. I was just questioning as to whether or not this is required?

Currently my combobox displays "AdminID" where as I would rather it display "AdminName"

Thanks.

```
Dim objConnection As New   OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= InfoSystem.accdb")
Dim objAdminDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select *from tblAdmins", objConnection)
Dim objAdminCB As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(objAdminDA)
Dim objDataSet As New DataSet()

Public Sub Retrieve()

    'Clears DataSet of any existing data
    objDataSet.Clear()
    'Fills schema - adds table structure information to DataSet
    objAdminDA.FillSchema(objDataSet, SchemaType.Source, "tblAdmins")
    'Fills DataSet with info from the DataAdapter
    objAdminDA.Fill(objDataSet, "tblAdmins")

    'Fill the DataSet with info from the Admin table
    objAdminDA.FillSchema(objDataSet, SchemaType.Source, "tblAdmins")
    objAdminDA.Fill(objDataSet, "tblAdmins")

    'Empty combo box
    cboxAdmin.Items.Clear()

    'Loop through each row, adding the AdminName to the combo box
    Dim i As Integer, strAdminID As String
    For i = 1 To objDataSet.Tables("tblAdmins").Rows.Count
        strAdminID = objDataSet.Tables("tblAdmins").Rows(i - 1).Item("AdminID")
        cboxAdmin.Items.Add(strAdminID)
    Next
    'Select first item in the list
    cboxAdmin.SelectedIndex = 0

    FillAdminDetails()

End Sub

Public Sub FillAdminDetails()
    Dim objRow As DataRow
    objRow = objDataSet.Tables("tblAdmins").Rows.Find(cboxAdmin.SelectedItem.ToString)
    txtStaffDept.Text = objRow.Item("Department")
    txtStaffTitle.Text = objRow.Item("Title")
End Sub

Private Sub cboxAdmin_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboxAdmin.SelectedIndexChanged
    FillAdminDetails()
End Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a compelling reason **not** to have a PK?

Comment: The whole concept of database design hinges on tables having a PK.

Comment: The format of my forms and other tables slightly contradict each other, not a huge necessity but would make things slightly easier. Questioning out of my own curiosity also to try understand this code better.

Comment: ComboBox currently displays "AdminID", I would prefer if it displayed my "AdminName". However, AdminID is better suited as a PK.

Comment: If the answer fixed your problem, please click the checkmark next to it so this gets removed from the UnAnswered list.  I mention this because you havent accepted ANY of the answers you have gotten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CBO shows `AdminID` because that is what you fill it with. If you *bind* the table to the CBO, you can use `DisplayMember` to show one thing, and `ValueMember` to return another to your code:

```
Private ACEConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= InfoSystem.accdb"
Private dtAdmin As DataTable
...
Private Sub SetupCBO
    Dim SQL = "SELECT AdminId, AdminName FROM tblAdmin"

    Using dbcon As New OleDbConnection(ACEConnStr)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, dbcon)

            dbcon.Open()
            dtAdmin = New DataTable

            dtAdmin.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
        End Using
    End Using

    cboAdmin.DataSource = dtAdmin
    cboAdmin.DisplayMember = "AdminName"     ' what to show
    cboAdmin.ValueMember = "AdminId"         ' what field to report
End Sub
```

The first thing to note is that there is no code to populate the CBO directly. Using a `DataSource`, the cbo will get the data from the underlying table.   The `DisplayMember` tells it which column to...well, display, and the `ValueMember` allows your code to be able to fetch that PrimaryKey/Id to positively know which "Steve" or "Bob" is logging in.

Also note that you don't absolutely need a `DataAdapter` just to fill one table. Nor do you *need* `DataSet`. As shown, you can use the `Load` method with a `DataReader` to directly fill a table.   The `Using` blocks close and dispose of those objects freeing resources.

When bound, you would generally use the `SelectedValueChanged` event and use the `.SelectedValue`.

In this case, the `SelectedItem` will be a `DataRowView` object because NET creates a `DataView` wrapper.  If the data source was a `List(Of Employee)` or a `List(of Widget)`, the `SelectedItem` will *be* the selected `Employee` or `Widget`.

Comment: Thanks, will implement now!