# How to retrieve the ID placed on combobox valuemember which has a display member of a name VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

I'm having trouble with this code, and it caused me a lot of headache. I don't understand but it seems that none of the other forums on the net could give me a satisfying solution. Here's my problem:

I have a table named `students` which obviously has a name and an ID. I used `combobox` on one of my forms to generate a list of student names inside of it, but when the user selects a name for example, the `ID` of that selected student's name will be retrieved (instead of the name) and would be placed inside a `Textbox`

So for example in my `combobox` there's a displayed names of the Student:

```
Student1

Student2

Student3
```

When the user selects `Student1` the ID of that student taken from the xampp (MariaDB) database (which is 123) will be fetched and store it to the `Textbox`

```
Textbox= 123
```

Then when I clicked the `submit button` this would be stored to another `table` of that same database.

Here's my code inside the Form1_Load:

```
Using connection
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY fname ASC"
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        With cmbStudents
            .DataSource = ds.Tables("students")
            .DisplayMember = "fname" '//Note: This one works fine, it did display the names of the students.
            .ValueMember = "ID" '//Note: This is a contrary, coz when I tried to display it on the Textbox1.Text=cmbStudents.ValueMember it only display the string "fname" as it is. And not the ID itself which I thought it should be.
       End With
End Using
```

Here's my code when calling supposed ID value of the Combobox:

```
 Private Sub cmbStudents_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbStudents.SelectionChangeCommitted
    TextBox1.Text = cmbStudents.ValueMember '//Note: I also tried to use TextBox1.Text = cmbStudents.SelectedValue.ToString coz one of the forums I've visited says it might work. But that also has no effect. I've even changed the Textbox1_Textchanged into _selectionchangecommitted with ByVal but nothing happens.
End Sub
```

Anyone who can answer it? You guys are `Genius`
Thanks in advance. And please, I need it `ASAP` if that is okay with you?

**UPDATED:**
atlast! Guys, after a moment or so, when I tried to rerun the whole program again, finally, it works!

I dunno what happened, its just suddenly begins to work. Now I can save the ID to a textbox. Thanks for those who've tried to help though. ^_^

Comment: You forgot important fact, your question. At the same time could you say what works and what doesn't.

Comment: DisplayMember and ValueMember  are how you tell the control what to show and what to return to your code.  Use SelectedValue for the item selected which will the be the DB item. [Pretty much a duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36142596/1070452)

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix but as you can see on my last code sample, the SelectedValue is also not working :(

Comment: No I cant see that.  SelectedValue  is not ValueMember.  SelectedValue is nowhere in your post

Comment: @Plutonix please take a closer look at my comment on the last sample sir. It says, 

`Private Sub cmbStudents_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbStudents.SelectionChangeCommitted
    TextBox1.Text = cmbStudents.ValueMember '//Note: I also tried to use TextBox1.Text = cmbStudents.SelectedValue.ToString coz one of the forums I've visited says it might work. But that also has no effect. I've even changed the Textbox1_Textchanged into _selectionchangecommitted with ByVal but nothing happens.
End Sub`