# How To Load vb.net Combobox faster

Tags: mysql, vb.net, data-binding, combobox

i am New With Vb.net, I use This Code To load A Combobox from a Mysql Database.
Works good, but Slowly

Is there any way to Perform All This in One Query and load All Comboboxs Or Another Way To Perform This task Faster?

```
    AbrirDB()
    comandomysql.CommandText = "select distinct TblMarcas.marca from TblMarcas order by marca"
    Try
        Lector = comandomysql.ExecuteReader
        Lector.Read()
        .cbom.Properties.Items.Clear()
        If Lector.HasRows Then
            .cbom.Properties.Items.Add(Lector.Item("marca"))
            Do While Lector.Read
                .cbom.Properties.Items.Add(Lector.Item("marca"))
            Loop
        Else
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show(Err.Number & Err.Description)
        If conexion.State = ConnectionState.Open Then conexion.Close()
    End Try
    CerrarDb()




    'CARGO  Categorias a treelist
    AbrirDB()
    comandomysql.CommandText = "select distinct TblCategorias.categoria from TblCategorias order by categoria ASC"
    Try
        Lector = comandomysql.ExecuteReader
        Lector.Read()
        .cboc.Properties.Items.Clear()
        If Lector.HasRows Then
            .cboc.Properties.Items.Add(Lector.Item("categoria"))
            Do While Lector.Read
                .cbocategoria.Properties.Items.Add(Lector.Item("categoria"))
            Loop
        Else

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show(Err.Number & Err.Description)
        If conexion.State = ConnectionState.Open Then conexion.Close()
    End Try
    CerrarDb()


    'CARGO Subcategorias
    AbrirDB()
    comandomysql.CommandText = "select distinct TblSubcategorias.subcategoria from TblSubcategorias order by subcategoria ASC"
    Try
        Lector = comandomysql.ExecuteReader
        Lector.Read()
        .cbos.Properties.Items.Clear()
        If Lector.HasRows Then
            .cbos.Properties.Items.Add(Lector.Item("subcategoria"))
            Do While Lector.Read
                .cbos.Properties.Items.Add(Lector.Item("subcategoria"))
            Loop

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show(Err.Number & Err.Description)
        If conexion.State = ConnectionState.Open Then conexion.Close()
    End Try
    CerrarDb()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fill a DataTable and bind the CBO.DataSource to it   Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36142887/1070452

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    myCombo.SuspendLayout()
        dim Table as new DataTable()
    table.Load(MyDataReader)
    myCombo.DataSource=table
    myCombo.DisplayMember="column1"
    myCombo.ResumeLayout()

Comment: i try it but is more slowly than load with a While and Loop

Answer (score 0):

```
combo.Items.Clear()
Dim ds As DataTable = yourtable
Dim arr As Object() = (From dc In ds.AsEnumerable Select dc(0)).ToArray
combo.Items.AddRange(arr)
```